# How to find the biggest sum of properties for object inside object?

Tags: javascript, properties, sum, javascript-objects

I have a problem and don't know how to solve it. :(

I have a script there objects inside object, such as:

```
var s = {
  1: {
    type: "main",
    ...
    values: {
      speed: 10,
      dexterity: 5,
      jump: 1
    }
  },
  2: {
    type: "main",
    ...
    values: {
      speed: 8,
      dexterity: 3,
      jump: 13
    }
  },
  3: ...
}
```

I need to find within `s` object an element that has biggest sum of some `values` object properties.

For example, I need to find an object which has highest sum of properties `speed` and `dexterity`.

Here is the element no.1, because it has sum `10+5` instead of no.2 which sum is `8+3`.

Comment: I see you're using increasing non-negative integers as properties of an object. Why not use an array instead?

Comment: @RickViscomi That could come from a database and be an auto incrementing primary key

Comment: @RickViscomi, the integers that i have used is only for example. Instead of numbers there are some titles

Comment: Ok, just an observation

Comment: If these were instances of a common object, you might consider adding a custom `valueOf` method that returns `this.speed + this.dexterity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getMax(obj) {
    var max = 0;
    var maxKey;
    for (var key in obj) {
        var cur = obj[key];
        var values = cur.values;
        var total = values.speed + values.dexterity;
        if (total > max) {
            max = total;
            maxKey = key;
        }
    }
    return maxKey;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xn8WC/2/

It will return the key (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc.) of the object with the highest total.

You call it like `getMax(s);`.

Comment: @lan, frankly, I do not really want to use loops as in the object more than 1000 items.

Comment: @NikitaShelimov Whether you want to or not, they will be used - either explicitly by **your** code or internally by an object's specific method.

Comment: @NikitaShelimov I updated my answer to not do as much work with `arguments` and just assume we're working with `speed` and `dexterity` only. Here's a jsperf to show both of my functions are faster than the `filter` solution: http://jsperf.com/for-loops-vs-filter-logic . It's hard to truly test because the object only has 3 items, not 1000

Comment: @lan indeed, loop is faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find this which lets you choose from predefined properties to sum;

```
function largest(s, speed, dexterity, jump) {
    var i, j, b = {i: null, j: -Infinity};
    for (i in s) { // loop over every key
        j =   ((    speed || 0) && s[i].values.speed    ) // add chosen
            + ((dexterity || 0) && s[i].values.dexterity)
            + ((     jump || 0) && s[i].values.jump     );
        if (j > b.j) b.i = i, b.j = j; // if largest, remember
    }
    return b.i; // return key of largest
}
```

Using example `s`,

```
largest(s, 1, 1, 0); // 1
largest(s, 1, 0, 1); // 2
```

Answer (score -1):

given the code above,

```
var biggest= s[Object.keys(s).filter(function(a,b,c){ 
   a=s[a];
   return (b=a.values.speed + a.values.dexterity) > this[0] ?
      (this[0]=b) : 0;
}, [0]).slice(-1)[0]];
```